# Enter Key on Input Automatically Tab to Next Input with Fields in iFrames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

I have a form with inputs which also has an iFrame embedded in the form which also has inputs (pseudo HTML):

```
<input type="text" name="one" value="one" />
<input type="text" name="two" value="two" />
<input type="text" name="three" value="three" />
<iframe
  <input type="text" name="bacon" value="bacon">
</iframe>
<input type="text" name="four" value="four" />
<input type="text" name="five" value="five" />
```

When the user presses tab they are taken from input to input even inside the iframe fields selecting **bacon** after **three**.  We all love bacon.

I also have some javascript that attempts to focus the next input on enter key:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(ev) {
    // Move to next on enter
    if (ev.which === 13) {
      var inputs = $(':tabbable');
      var next = inputs.index(this) + 1;
      var input = inputs.eq(next == inputs.length ? 0 : next);
      input.focus();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is the javascript enter key code never focuses the **bacon** field, it will skip right over it.  jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/54n8mqkh/4/

Let's all skip answers that include not using the iFrame.  I know it is not an ideal implementation.  However, I would accept ANY answer that allows the enter key to move through all the fields consistently including the iframe using any type of javascript.  It does not have to be jquery specific.

I have tried a few different approaches to solve this but none I have found works.  Thanks in advance to anyone who has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus inside of the iframe like so :

```
var frameBody = $("#IFrame_input").contents().find("input");

frameBody.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question - after a few more hours I was able to solve my use case by expanding my selector to include the iframe.  Then I build the array of inputs manually and while iterating I checked the node type for an iframe.  If / when I encountered an iframe, I did the same select inside the iframe and added the inputs within the iframe:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Parent level helper function
  window.tabToNext = function(me) {
    var selector = ':tabbable, iframe';

    var inputElems = [];
    $(selector).each(function(index) {
      var nodeName = $(this).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
      if (nodeName == 'iframe') {
        $(this).contents().find(selector).each(function(index) {
          inputElems.push(this);
        });
      } else {
        inputElems.push(this);
      }
    });      

    var inputs = $(inputElems);
    var next = inputs.index(me) + 1;
    if (next == inputs.length) next = 0;

    var input = inputs.eq(next);
    input.focus();
    return false;
  }

  $(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(ev) {
    // Move to next on enter
    if (ev.which === 13) {
      return window.tabToNext(this);
    }
  });

  // Focus the first input
  $('input[name=one]').focus();
});
```

**FWIW:** I could not just expand the selector as best I could tell and also I tried to use $.add to build the collection starting with an empty jQuery collection:

```
var foo = $([]);
foo.add(someElement);
```

... but it does not honor the order you add.  It will re-order to the DOM according to the docs which SEEMS like it should be right, but for some reason my iframe child fields always ended up last and messed up the tab order.

Anyhow, I hope if someone else has this issue some day you find this helpful. Working solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/wbs1zajs/6/

Comment: Also, what you may not see in the fiddle is that the iframe fiddle calls back to the parent fiddle for the navigation to work seamlessly which implies the same  origin policy - be warned.